# background-image is not rendering on my local website

Tags: html, css, django

i have been struggling with rendering my background image on my local website. I was searching the forum and did everyhing I could but still issues. Would you please take a look?

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'books/theme.css' %}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'books:index' %}">The Bookstore</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="{% url 'books:index' %}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Books
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>


            </div>
        </div>


    </nav>


</body>
```

and CSS:

```
body{
background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252_1280.jpg");
}
```

Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: working fine check now,  https://jsfiddle.net/2gL10jrf/1/

Comment: Thanks, I have probably some issues in the project itself. Probably accessing .css

Comment: Please make sure that you've called the static template tag to build the URL `{% load static %}` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thanks, I am doing with {% load staticfiles %}

Comment: which is wrong and must be `{% load static %}` as johirpro said.

Comment: Sadly it is not working even with {% load static %} :-)

Comment: OK, I have been debugging a little bit, it is not about the css file but the image itself.